# why the value of `*args` is strange?

Tags: python

Here is my code snappt:

```
class C(dict):
    def __init__(*args, **kwds):
        print 'args = {}'.format(args)
        print 'kwds = {}'.format(kwds)
        if not args:
            raise TypeError("descriptor '__init__' of 'Counter' object needs an argument")

        self = args[0]

        args = args[1:]

        if len(args) > 1:
            raise TypeError('expected at most 1 arguments, got %d' % len(args))

        super(C, self).__init__()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = C()
```

When i run this code, i am confused with the output:

```
C:\Users\elqstux\Desktop>python wy.py
args = ({},)
kwds = {}
```

For `c = C()`, i think the code will raise a Error, because `args` will be `()` in this case, but from the output, `args` is `({},)`, what't the reason?

`self, args = args[0], args[1:]  # allow the "self" keyword be passed`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does \*\* (double star) and \* (star) do for Python parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-python-parameters)

Comment: @Signal, i know `*args` will be a `tuple`, but why it is `({},)` in my case, why not `()`?

Comment: @Signal invalid duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`*args` is `({},)` because you didn't declare an explicit `self` parameter. So when `__init__` is called, the `self` parameter ends up becoming the first element in `args`. Since you inherit from `dict`, you get `dict`'s `repr`, which is `{}`.

This trick is used intentionally in Python's `dict` subclasses nowadays, because otherwise code that initialized the `dict` subclass with `mydict(self=123)` would break the initializer. The fix is to do:

```
 def __init__(*args, **kwargs):
     self, *args = args
     # On Python 2 without unpacking generalizations you'd use the more repetitive:
     # self, args = args[0], args[1:]
```

which forces `self` to be accepted purely as a positional argument (which is passed implicitly by the instance construction machinery). For an example of real world usage, see [the implementation of `collections.Counter`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/426ac89548b3/Lib/collections/__init__.py#l512).

Comment: Why `mydict(self=123)` will break the legacy if i write `def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):`? what's the purpose using `def __init__(*args, **kwds):`?

Comment: @BlackMamba: Try it out yourself. The problem is that when you accept `self` by name, it can  be passed both positionally (by Python initialization machinery) and by keyword, and doing `mydict(self=123)` is now trying to pass `self` twice (instead of creating a `dict` with key `'self'`), which triggers `TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'self'`. Python isn't smart enough to use the positional `self` and put the keyword `self` in `kwargs`, so you need to help it out.

Comment: `self, args = args[0], args[1:]  # allow the "self" keyword be passed·`

Comment: @BlackMamba: That's how you'd have to do it in Python 2; in Python 3, using `*` in plain expressions (not just function calls) is possible (and generalized almost completely in 3.5), so you can do `self, *args = args` which is less repetitive and generalizes to other scenarios (`args` is always a sequence in this case so slicing is possible, but it couldn't be done w/an iterator/generator, while `x, *y, z = mygeneratorfunction()` still works seamlessly & fast in Py3, but would require the ugly/slow: `gen = mygeneratorfunction()`, `x = next(gen)`, `y = list(gen)`, `z = y.pop()` to work on Py2).

Answer (score 3):

I was intrigued by your output! The reason is clear enough: you ommitted `self` from the `__init__` function definition. Running the example with a regular class will make it clear what happened:

```
>>> class C():
...   def __init__(*args, **kwargs):
...     print args, kwargs
...
>>> C()
(<__main__.C instance at 0x103152368>,) {}
<__main__.C instance at 0x103152368>
```

Of course, `self` got stuck into `args` as the single element of the `args` tuple. `self` is just like any other argument, after all.

What made it more puzzling in your case is that since you subclassed `dict`, the `repr()` of your class at that point was `{}`, i.e. the `repr()` of an empty dict. Hence the `({},)`.

Answer (score 1):

Your class `__init__` function is being called with a single argument, the implicit `self` argument (i.e., the new class instance that's being created).  Normally this would print as a class instance.  But because the class subclasses `dict`, it prints as a `dict`, initially with no elements.